# Interpolate variable inside \N

Tags: regex, perl

I want to make a script which should be able to transform the input to small capitals.
I've tried the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature qw(say);
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
my $text = join '',<STDIN>;
say $text=~s/[a-zA-Z]/\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL $&}/gr;
```

But I get

> Unknown charname '"LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL $&"' at small.pl line 7,
>   within string Execution of small.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

I am open to other ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\N{}` is a compile-time construct. Use [charnames](http://p3rl.org/charnames) to look up a character by name at run-time.

```
perl -C -mcharnames -E'
    say chr charnames::vianame(
        "LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL " . $_
    ) for qw(I N R)
'
```

Comment: The OP's original code would do multiple substitutions per string. To that end, one would apply your solution as follows: `use charnames (); say $text =~ s/[a-zA-Z]/ chr(charnames::vianame("LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL $&")) /egr;`

Answer (score 1):

`\N{}` is a compile-time construct. One solution is therefore to generate code and evaluate it. `s///` has built-in support for this in the form of `/ee`.

```
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use feature qw(say);

my $text = 'A';
say $text =~ s/([a-zA-Z])/ qq{"\\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL $1}"} /eer;
```

How this works:

1. The first `e` causes `qq{"\\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL $1}"}` to be evaluated, producing `"\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL A}"`.
2. The second `e` causes `"\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL A}"` to be evaluated, producing `ᴀ`.
3. The `A` is substituted with `ᴀ`.